# How to capture the url of the page that threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It's simple enough to grab the current URL with

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
```

In fact, that's the accepted answer to [this very similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344440/how-to-get-which-page-threw-an-exception-to-application-error-in-aspx)
However, I've implemented application wide error handling, and have an ErrorController that generates emails that are sent back to us when there is an unhandled exception.  If I implement the code snippet above in the Error Controller, the URL I get back is something like

```
http://.../Error/GenericError?aspxerrorpath=/Controller/ErrorProneAction
```

How can I grab the url of the page that actually threw the error?  That is, something more like

```
http://.../Controller/ErrorProneAction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment - do you have a function like `void Application_OnError(object sender, EventArgs e)` in your global.asax? If so, then you should be able to get the information you are looking for.

```
protected void Application_OnError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var app = (MvcApplication)sender;
    var context = app.Context;
    string path = context.Request.PathWithQueryString;
    ...
```

Gives you something like `/controllerOrRoute/action?query=val`. Or you can use the RawUrl, or Url property to get basically the same thing. I just fired my application up to see what it generates and it looks like this is what you're asking for.

Edit: I should note that I tested the above for MVC3.

Comment: Thanks, I do have the method you mention in Global, and I am using mvc3 as well.  But if I add the code you've posted, how do I access the correct url?  I'm still getting the results I mentioned in the OP with Request.Url in the controller, as if nothing has changed.

Comment: @Forty-Two hmm, that is a bummer. If it is anywhere, I would guess for sure it is in the context object. But if you can't find it maybe it doesn't exist :(

Comment: Guess I didn't really understand how to work with ApplicationState objects.  After defining Application["Path"] = path, this solution works for me.  Thanks, and I apologize if I'm a bit of a knucklehead at times;)

Answer (score 1):

See this blog post:

http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/11/how-to-handle-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/

If you pass a parameter to your `ActionResult`, this will take the value of the `aspxerrorpath` query string value.

```
public ActionResult NotFound(string url)
{
  var originalUri = url ?? Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"] ?? Request.Url.OriginalString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Passing in the url does not work, as it is always null for some reason.  The blog post you linked to is using the [HandleError] attribute, and I'm not.  I've got an Application Error method in Global.asax instead.  Perhaps that's the difference here.  I do like the Request.QueryString call.  That may actually suffice on it's own.