# Catch Error with Custome Error Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I'm defining a custom Error page in ASP.NET

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Oops.aspx"></customErrors>
```

When an Error occurs, I'm being redirect to that page with the following URL:

```
Oops.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/WebForm1.aspx
```

In the `Page Load` method of the `Oops.aspx` page, I'm trying to catch the error:

```
Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
if (exc != null)
{
    //do something
}
```

However, it seems that `exc` is actually `null` because none of the actions defined in that condition statement are being executed.

Comment: If you are logging the error in a datastore, the best way you can achieve this is by logging that error in `Application_Error` method of Global.asax, and then redirect to the `Oops.aspx?refId=yourerrorId` with the key of the error record that was stored in the datastore.

Comment: @Nilesh how to retrieve the page that caused the error in Global.asax?

Comment: @AliBassam http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344440/how-to-get-which-page-threw-an-exception-to-application-error-in-aspx

Comment: @Nilesh Your solution was better and it worked. Post it as an Answer Please.

Comment: Sorry I did not see your last two comments. but you already found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logging the error in a datastore, the best way you can achieve this is by logging that error in Application_Error method of Global.asax, and then redirect to the Oops.aspx?refId=yourerrorId with the key of the error record that was stored in the datastore.